# Clone Duping glitch

Tags: mit-scratch

I am trying to make a clicker game on scratch and I made a click effect that is a mini version of the button that floats to the bottom of the screen. I got everything worked out except for one thing. For some reason, every time you click, (except for the first time) the click effect multiplies by 2! I don't know what is happening or how to fix it.

I only tried to use the delete clone block, but I'm already out of ideas.
I was expecting multiple to be able to be on screen at once, but not multiple to spawn at once when you click!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a block "When this sprite is clicked" in your sprite.

If you create a clone of that sprite, the subsequent clicks will be handled by that new clone too (effectively doubling the number of clones with each click).

To fix that, you need a sprite-only variable that will tell you which of the clones is the original sprite, and only create new clones from that.